# Maven, CDI (WELD) and interfaces packages

Tags: maven, cdi

first of all, I'm not an expert in this subject, that's why I'm asking ...

I have two Maven modules, both exposing several interfaces. One module deals with the business logic (BL), the other one is a gateway to external systems (GW).
As long as the gateway serves as outgoing gateway, there is no problem with circular dependencies as it is like this:

BL =depends=> GW

The interfaces of the gateway are injected into the business logic by @Inject, everything works fine.

Module: BusinessLogic:

```
public class BusinessLogicBean {
    @Inject private GatewayInterface interface;

    public void sendStuff(Param myParam) {
         interface.doSend(myParam);
    }
```

Module: Gateway

```
public Interface GatewayInterface {
   void doSend(Param someParam);

public class GatewayInterfaceBean {
    public void doSend(Param someParam) {
    //implementation goes here
```

As soon as I have incoming invocations which needs to be delegated to the business logic I can't specify:

BL =depends=> GW =depends=> BL

as Maven will complain about cirdular dependencies.

Therefore I decided to have a dedicated interfaces module of the gateway, so the dependencies are as follows:

BL =depends=> I_GW <=depends= GW =depends=> BL

So far so good despite of the fact, that @Inject right now complaints about unresolved dependencies, the same code as above isn't working anymore.

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type OrderProcess with qualifiers @Default
```

at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private de.xyz.abc.externalaccess.control.AccessServiceBean.process
  at de.xyz.abc.externalaccess.control.AccessServiceBean.process(AccessServiceBean.java:0)

This is how the modules look like:
Module: BusinessLogic:

```
public class BusinessLogicBean {
    @Inject private GatewayInterface interface;
```

Module: Interfaces_Gateway

```
public Interface GatewayInterface {
   void doSend(Param someParam);
```

Module: Gateway

```
 public class GatewayInterfaceBean {
    public void doSend(Param someParam) {
    //implementation goes here


public class ProvisioningServiceTest {

private static SeContainer container;
private static ProvisioningService service;

@Test
public void testPostApplications() {
    service.postApplications(null);
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    SeContainerInitializer weld = Weld.newInstance();
    container = weld.initialize();
    service = container.select(ProvisioningService.class).get();
}

@AfterClass
public static void shutDown() {
    container.close();
}
```

}

The bang happens **within @BeforeClass**, which part am I missing? **As long as the interface and the implementation resides in the same module, everything is fine, but as soon as I split it into two modules ...**

beans.xml (in all three modules within META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
<interceptors>
   <class>de.abc.util.interceptor.CallTracingInterceptor</class>
   <class>de.abc.util.interceptor.PerformanceTracingInterceptor</class>
   <class>de.abc.util.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor</class>
 </interceptors>
</beans>
```

WELD 3.1.1

BTW, using this approach with WildFly and the @EJB annotation doesn't cause a problem at all, but Wildfly unfortunately is no option here.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: So you can get this to work when not using maven but manually generated jar files?

Comment: Hi, packaging is not the issue as mvn package runs fine ... It happens during test when the unit test accesses the interface package.

Comment: Then why did you tag the question with maven and even used it in your title? Please correct that.

Comment: Coz of the dependencies ... maybe?

Comment: I guess the problem is twofold ... one is to avoid circular dependencies, the other one is CDI with distributed interfaces and implementations between the modules.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, one bean in the chain of dependencies should be @ApplicationScoped or @SessionScoped. The references will be proxies, which can be resolved as soon as necessary at runtime.